# WP7: Can I change font size of Panorama view? in silverlight work

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, font-size, panorama-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change font size of Panorama item header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019009/how-to-change-font-size-of-panorama-item-header)

I have coded panorama view like this:

```
`<controls:Panorama Title="test">`
```

in WP7 silverlight. Is anyway I can change the font size or event font family?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019009/how-to-change-font-size-of-panorama-item-header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

You can using template for this.

For example

```
<controls:Panorama Title="test">
<controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,80,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Panorama.TitleTemplate>
</controls:Panorama>
```